# Lost my external Hard Drive when creating installation media (Boot Disc). Lost files?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, external-hard-drive, file-recovery

I accidentally or cluelessly used my ( main partition ) **external 1TB HD** to create *installation media for Windows 10:*

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

I didn't think it through and now I have a *32GB* Boot Drive **ESD-USB (E:)** (Wich didn't work, for some reason "No operating system found" message...) and the rest of the 900+ GB are lost or simply *invisible or hidden (I hope)*

Anyway, The external HD was over 400GB of files.

Used recovery software (Recuva and Puran, portables) wich limits (apparently) to 32 GB or so, and another (currently scanning...) EaseUS Data Recovery actually allowed me to select a 900GB "LOST!!! partition". And found files waay over 1TB plus they are unnamed!!!

Please, help

Can the "lost partition" be found or recovered without information loss?
What procedure would you recommend?

Thanks in advance. Good Night.

Comment: The file names are stored within the MFT - "master file table". Most recovery tools will look at both the MFT and the actual drive data, scanning for commonalities for specific files to be able to recover as much as possible. However, only the MFT stores the file names, timestamps and certain other meta data. If your MFT was outside the 32GB that was lost, you might be ok. But that's an extremely unlikely scenario.

Comment: @10Y01, sadly I did the exact same thing as you!  Personally, I think Microsoft should put a warning prompt in between the drive being selected and acceptance of the drive to prevent this from happening - I dont' recall seeing any warning about the drive being formatted.  Anyway, I was wondering if you have any advice and how you were able to to recover the data with original file names?  I do have a backup of my drive, but sadly, it's several months old and I'm hoping to recover my more recent data.  Any advice that you'd give?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now I realize that you mean you've formatted the external drive, and it's not your main system drive

First of all, 32gb worth the data has been destroyed, and some other data has probably been corrupted. On the upside though, the majority of your data is safe and sound. Don't do anything to that drive for the moment, as it will just destroy/corrupt more data.

It sounds like you were 90% of the way to having fixed the issue yourself. Looking at how EaseUS is setup, if you relaunch it, and "scan" that lost partition, you can recover the data to another location. (I'm 80% sure that you can't initially recover it to the same drive, since the drivespace isn't partitioned. However, if there's an option within EaseUS to recover to the same drive, for all I know, it could be possible) I don't know how much drivespace you have available to you outside of that external drive, but I think that would be your only option (aside from the potential option i listed in parenthesis earlier)

Anyways, That's it. As long as you don't write anything else to that hard drive or melt the platters, your data (aside from the already corrupted bit from the recovery media) should be perfectly fine. 
I'm not sure about EaseUS, but I believe Recuva shows what files are intact, and what is damaged/corrupted and to what to degree.

By the way, [here is a reference](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-formatted-partition.htm) to help with scanning/recovering the data in EaseUS, and I [think this proves](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/files-corrupted-after-data-recovery.html) what I was thinking about not wanting to recover to the same drive. First Paragraph under **"How to recover and repair corrupted files from hard disk after recovery"**, *"we always recommend them to choose a different location to save the recovered data, to prevent data overwriting from happening"*

Misread the question almost entirely and didn't even realize how it was mildly impossible the way I interpreted it. Below is my original response, feel free to straight up ignore it.

> I'd like to comment and ask for some info to help me/others, but I
>   don't have enough rep, so I'll deliver as complete of an answer as I
>   can.
>
> If EaseUS says there's a lost partition, there likely is just a
>   partition sitting somewhere with all of your data on it. First, let's
>   find out what partition that is.
>
> First, check your filexplorer's "this PC" tab, to see if there's a
>   visible partition you can access next to your "windows (c:)" drive. If
>   there's nothing there, continue down.
>
> 1. From your taskbar search bar, type CMD, right click command prompt, and run it as an administrator
> 2. Type `DISKPART` & press enter
> 3. Type `List volume` & press enter
> 4. Identify the letter of the "missing space" volume by looking at the size column (should be around 900gb from what you say)
>
> Now you have two routes. First route) Open file explorer, and type
>   `<letter>:` into the filepath bar at the top. If you see a lot of
>   files, voila, your data is there. Now, migrate all of your data to an
>   external drive, as the next step will likely purge your data, and
>   follow the "Merge partitions with diskpart" section of [this guide](https://www.partition-magic-server.com/howto/merge-partitions-and-unallocated-space.html)
>   to delete that partition, and merge the now unallocated space into
>   your main drive. Then just port your data back from the external
>   drive, to your main drive
>
> Second Route) Follow [this guide](https://www.hdd-tool.com/tutorials/merge-partition.html#.XB2lXuJ7mM8) to use a third party software
>   (NIUBI Partition editor) to just merge the partitions without having
>   to move your data and move it back. I personally haven't used the
>   software before, but I've no reason to think it's malicious, and a
>   quick search reveals nothing to it's discredit.
>
> Good luck!

Comment: Hello Stark Thanks for your answer. List Disk lists 2 HD local HD and THE external HD (size : 931GB) (Available:  899GB) - List volume only shows E: ESD-USB FAT32 (32GB) - List partition list none of the External HD. So We get a 1TB disk but only a 32 GB volume and no partitions...

Comment: That is 900GB Unassigned and the 32GB primary for the installation media

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question almost entirely and didn't even realize that it would've been mildly impossible the way I thought it was.. 

I'm writing an edit right now to address what you should **actually** do.

Comment: @FernandoYP Answer edited with what should be the info you need

Comment: From the answer I understan that the data has been deleted and the only option is recovery, wich is "complicated" since the application has alrready scanned over 2GB of data and the names are mostly "not the original ones" plus some file extensions do noteven  show up. Thanks a lot for your Help Stark. I'll be more carefull from now on and double back up my most sensitive information.

Comment: Deleted is a fuzzy term.. basically when you delete something (move to recycle and “permanently delete” or format a drive, for instance), the data isn’t actually gone perse, rather it’s marked as “free”. You could still recover it, but it won’t appear on the system, and the system treats it like nothing is there, allowing other data to be written ontop of it. Only 32gb of data has been overwritten in your case. Unless you need your drive ASAP or you want your drive space back faster instead of the data, I would let the scan sit for as long as it needs to to find everything it can.